# Listing "Note" Publications in CV

Tags: publications, cv

In some journals, "notes" are original research papers that are not significant enough to be a "regular contribution". If I've published a note, can I list it in my CV as if it is a regular publication (i.e., not mentioning that it is a note)? Could this be considered as dishonest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't consider it dishonest, if only because I personally don't list them separately. The fact that they are notes ("squibs" we call them in my field) can generally be inferred directly from the low page count.

But then, the number of such very short publications is a very small fraction of all my publications. If it was a significant fraction, maybe I would consider a separate section.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best practice is insert in your curriculum a section "Note".

I do not work in recruitment sector, but I like honesty.